# $.get command running out of sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am have a JavaScript that is not running in sequence.  The script establishes an unload function.  It uses the $.get jQuery command to retrieve a file, then it is supposed to print the file to the external device.  I added some alert boxes, so I would know whether it is running every function, and I discovered it is trying to print before it is retrieving the file.  I changed my code so it retrieved the file on an unload function, the prints the file on an on click function and it works perfectly.  Is there a reason the it is running the $.get command out of sequence?

Comment: Andrew, Java and JavaScript are entirely different languages.

Comment: Please add you code so we can see whats going on.

Comment: I'll lay £10 that the cause of the problem is that you haven't understood what "asynchronous" means in AJAX, but it's impossible to say without seeing the code...

Comment: My apologies, please for give my ignorance.  I am using JavaScript within my web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX requests get sent, but the processing continues - it does not stall until the response is received.

So if you want things to go sequentially you need to do the processing in a closure:

```
$.get(url, function(response)
{
   // Process the response

   // do other stuff
};
```

Not:

```
$.get(url);

// do other stuff
```